How to use Zero Noise Extrapolation (ZNE) with qiskit circuit?
I am trying to understand the Zero Noise Extrapolation (ZNE). I am looking for some sample code which can apply ZNE to a very basic quantum circuit and then run it on some Fake qiskit hardware and and get me the results in the form of counts.
It would be great if someone can help me on this.
Edit_1
I am editing the question, trying to use mitiq https://mitiq.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/ibmq-backends.html
import qiskit
from qiskit_aer import QasmSimulator
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService
from mitiq import zne
from mitiq.interface.mitiq_qiskit.qiskit_utils import initialized_depolarizing_noise

USE_REAL_HARDWARE = False

qreg, creg = qiskit.QuantumRegister(1), qiskit.ClassicalRegister(1)
circuit = qiskit.QuantumCircuit(qreg, creg)
for _ in range(10):
    circuit.x(qreg)
circuit.measure(qreg, creg)
print(circuit)

if QiskitRuntimeService.saved_accounts() and USE_REAL_HARDWARE:
    service = QiskitRuntimeService()
    backend = service.least_busy(operational=True, simulator=False)
    noise_model = False
else:
    # Simulate the circuit with noise
    noise_model = initialized_depolarizing_noise(noise_level=0.02)
    # Default to a simulator
    backend = QasmSimulator(noise_model=noise_model)


def ibmq_executor(circuit: qiskit.QuantumCircuit, shots: int = 8192) -> float:
    """Returns the expectation value to be mitigated.

    Args:
        circuit: Circuit to run.
        shots: Number of times to execute the circuit to compute the expectation value.
    """
    # Transpile the circuit so it can be properly run
    exec_circuit = qiskit.transpile(
        circuit,
        backend=backend,
        basis_gates=noise_model.basis_gates if noise_model else None,
        optimization_level=0, # Important to preserve folded gates.
    )
    
    # Run the circuit
    job = backend.run(circuit, shots=shots)

    # Convert from raw measurement counts to the expectation value
    counts = job.result().get_counts()
    print(counts)
    return counts

unmitigated = ibmq_executor(circuit)
print(unmitigated)

mitigated = zne.execute_with_zne(circuit, ibmq_executor)
print(mitigated)

The zne.execute_with_zne API needs circuit and ibmq_executor(which returns expectation_value but my requirement is counts). If I returns counts from ibmq_executorfunction, I will get error.
Need help.

Check out mitiq https://mitiq.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/ibmq-backends.html

Thanks for the response @RefikMansuroglu. I edited the question. Please review.

You say, you require counts. This makes sense in the unmitigated case. What outcome do you expect in the mitigated case? ZNE is applied to observable expectation values, not counts, as far as I am concerned.

I want the counts in the mitigated case @RefikMansuroglu but I am not sure how to get that?

I am not sure what that means. Do you have a reference on how to apply ZNE to single shots rather than expectation values? Check out this preprint https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.10921

Actually, I am running some code on quantum hardware @RefikMansuroglu. I am getting bad counts results in the form as {'0000': 27, '0001': 45, ....}.  When I caculate the difference with desired result, it is way too much difference. So, I though of applying the ZNE to improve my hardware. But this API of mitiq cannot give results in the form of count.

The main confusion seems to lie in the application of ZNE to expectation values rather than to single shot measurements. Let $O$ be an observable and $\langle O \rangle$ an expectation value on some state of interest. Let further $0 < p < 1$ be the noise rate and $\lambda \geq 0$ a noise scaling parameter that can be tuned within $\lambda \in [1, \infty]$ and $\lambda = 0$ corresponds to the noise-free case. Tuning $\lambda$ often corresponds to making the computation deliberately worse, for instance by inserting redundant (noisy) gates that don't change the logic of the circuit.
What zero-noise extrapolation does, is given an ansantz for the dependence of $\langle O\rangle (\lambda)$ on $\lambda$ it samples different points in $\lambda \in [1, \infty]$ and then fits them to the function $\langle O\rangle (\lambda)$. Finally, evaluating $\langle O\rangle (\lambda=0)$ is supposed to reveal the noise-free expectation value.
Consider the following example on two qubits with $O = Z_1 Z_2$ and suppose you want to measure it on the state $\lvert 11 \rangle$. You can prepare this state with one $X$ gate on each qubit. If your quantum circuit suffers from a depolarizing channel $\mathcal{E}[\rho] = (1-p) \rho + \frac{p}{4} \mathbb{I}$ that is applied after every layer, then you could make the experiment worse by using three $X$ gates on each qubit as $X^3 = X$ or any odd number $\lambda = 2k+1, k \in \mathbb{N}_0$, leaving you with $$(1-p)^\lambda \lvert 11 \rangle \langle 11\rvert + \frac{1 - (1-p)^\lambda}{4}\mathbb{I}.$$
Now measuring $O$ will yield
$$\langle O\rangle (\lambda) = {\rm Tr}\left( \left( (1-p)^\lambda \lvert 11 \rangle \langle 11\rvert + \frac{1 - (1-p)^\lambda}{4}\mathbb{I} \right) Z_1 Z_2 \right) = (1-p)^\lambda.$$
This is an ansatz you could use now to measure the expectation value with one, three, five etc. layers yielding expectation values $\langle O\rangle (\lambda = 1), \langle O\rangle (\lambda=3), \langle O\rangle (\lambda=5)$ etc. Fitting the ansatz above will eventually give us the result, we are looking for $\langle O\rangle (0) = 1$.
Let me get back to your concern that is extrapolating the counts of a certain bitstring $b$. The outcome being the amplitudes of every computational basis state you basically ask for a part of a tomography that involves (exponentially) many measurements. In the two qubit example you could consider the state $\lvert \psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\lvert 00 \rangle + \lvert 11 \rangle \right)$. Measuring the counts of all bitstrings corresponds to measuring all Paulistrings containing $Z$ and $\mathbb{I}$ ($Z_{1/2}$ tells you the ratio of finding $0$ or $1$ in qubit 1 and 2, respectively, and $Z_1 Z_2$ gives you the correlation). You can then write the amplitude for bitstring $b$ as
$$|\langle b \vert \psi \rangle|^2 = {\rm Tr(\lvert b \rangle \langle b \rvert \psi \rangle \langle \psi \rvert) } = \frac{1}{4}\left( 1 + \sum_{P_Z} \langle b \vert P_Z \vert b \rangle \langle \psi \vert P_Z \vert \psi \rangle \right)$$
I singled out the identity as a trivial Z-string. Now you have to do three (for $n$ qubits $2^n - 1$) ZNEs for any of the Z-strings, make an ansatz fit the function and then calculate the relative count of shots with the above formula.
While this is in principle possible, I doubt this is what you want. Rather, you should directly make an ansatz for the observable that your quantum circuit is supposed to measure in the end.

Thank you the response @RefikMansuroglu.

You are welcome. What happened to the bounty btw?

I apolozise @RefikMansuroglu. I forgot to award it. The bounty got expired. The points got deducted from my account and still I cannot give it to anyone.
